# Added some code to site, it works correctly but seems to scroll infinitely beyond the footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple website, I added some code html, css, and JS. It seems the JS is now causing my page to extend infinitely beyond the footer. I would like for the page to end at the footer like normal.

I've tried messing around with different settings, I'm not a JS guru.
I have also done a lot of google searching, with no effective results.

Here is my code:

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const w = $(".w");
const ee = $(".ee");
const l = $(".l");
const c = $(".c");
const o = $(".o");
const m = $(".m");
const e = $(".e");

function transformLetters() {
  const scroll = window.scrollY;
  
  w.style.transform = `translate3d(0, ${scroll*2.4}px, 0) rotateY(${-scroll*1.03}deg)`;

  ee.style.transform = `translate3d(${-scroll*1.45}px, ${scroll*1.95}px, 0) rotate(${-scroll*1.1}deg)`;

  l.style.transform = `translate3d(${scroll*1.65}px, ${-scroll*2.05}px, 0) rotate(${scroll*1.2}deg)`;

  c.style.transform = `translate3d(0, ${scroll*2.75}px, 0) rotateY(${scroll*0.05}deg)`;

  o.style.transform = `translate3d(${-scroll*1.75}px, ${scroll*1.65}px, 0) rotate(${-scroll*1.3}deg)`;

  m.style.transform = `translate3d(0, ${-scroll*1.5}px, 0) rotateY(${scroll*1.05}deg)`;

  e.style.transform = `translate3d(${-scroll*1.45}px, ${-scroll*1.95}px, 0) rotate(${-scroll*1.1}deg)`;
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", transformLetters);
```

```css
.letters {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: hsl(0, 4%, 5%);
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
          perspective: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="letters">
  <span class="w">w</span>
  <span class="ee">e</span>
  <span class="l">l</span>
  <span class="c">c</span>
  <span class="o">o</span>
  <span class="m">m</span>
  <span class="e">e</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to reproduce the problem you mentionned. Is ther any other code that affects the scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chaska, thank you for your answer. While it didn't directly solve my problem, it did lead to the solution. I tried what you suggested but that lead to formatting issues with the header(I know I didn't share all the code). I made a small change to your addition, and it works thank you for your help!

```
            overflow: hidden;
            position: static;
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event

style code put in "window.requestAnimationFrame"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what other part is on the page.

You may try to add below css codes to fix the problem.

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const w = $(".w");
const ee = $(".ee");
const l = $(".l");
const c = $(".c");
const o = $(".o");
const m = $(".m");
const e = $(".e");

function transformLetters() {
  const scroll = window.scrollY;
  
  w.style.transform = `translate3d(0, ${scroll*2.4}px, 0) rotateY(${-scroll*1.03}deg)`;

  ee.style.transform = `translate3d(${-scroll*1.45}px, ${scroll*1.95}px, 0) rotate(${-scroll*1.1}deg)`;

  l.style.transform = `translate3d(${scroll*1.65}px, ${-scroll*2.05}px, 0) rotate(${scroll*1.2}deg)`;

  c.style.transform = `translate3d(0, ${scroll*2.75}px, 0) rotateY(${scroll*0.05}deg)`;

  o.style.transform = `translate3d(${-scroll*1.75}px, ${scroll*1.65}px, 0) rotate(${-scroll*1.3}deg)`;

  m.style.transform = `translate3d(0, ${-scroll*1.5}px, 0) rotateY(${scroll*1.05}deg)`;

  e.style.transform = `translate3d(${-scroll*1.45}px, ${-scroll*1.95}px, 0) rotate(${-scroll*1.1}deg)`;
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", transformLetters);
```

```css
.letters {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: hsl(0, 4%, 5%);
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
          perspective: 1200px;
  /* css to be added */
 overflow: hidden;
 position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
.other {
  height: 1400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="letters">
  <span class="w">w</span>
  <span class="ee">e</span>
  <span class="l">l</span>
  <span class="c">c</span>
  <span class="o">o</span>
  <span class="m">m</span>
  <span class="e">e</span>
</div>
<div class="other"></div>
```